# Javascript - check if div contains a word?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, contains

How can I check if a div contains a certain word?

```
var divs= document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0, len = divs.length; i < len; ++i) {

    if (divs[i].text = '*word*'){
    //do somthing
}
}
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 66):

use the *indexOf* function

```
if(divs[i].innerHTML.indexOf("word") !== -1) {
    // something
}
```

Comment: Replacing // something with divs[i].style.background = "red"; still highlights the entire page. How to get a reference for the div containing "word"? Granted, the question doesn't ask for that depth but for completion/curiosity it would be interesting.

Answer (score 20):

Use `includes()`:

```
node.textContent.includes('Some text');
```

Comment: includes is not yet stable. poorly supported

Comment: @Fred Randall
It looks well supported here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 4):

```
if (document.getElementById('divId').innerHTML.indexOf("word") != -1) { }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) function: `if (divs[i].text.indexOf('word') != -1) {`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a comparison operator not assign a variable.

```
if (divs[i].text == '*word*'){
```

I would recommend to use `indexOf`.

```
if (divs[i].text.indexOf('*word*') != -1){
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what others said about using `.indexOf()` function, I'd like to say `.text` is not a div node property. User `.innerHTML`

```
if (divs[i].innerHTML.indexOf('word') > -1){}
```

Comment: that will match HTML tag content too (i.e. tag names and attribute names and values).

Comment: It wasn't specified what type of content he was looking for.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think it's pretty clear the OP was looking to match text content, not markup.

Answer (score 2):

Gosh, so many answers!

To get just the text of an element, the simple way is to use *`textContent`* or, were not supported, *`innerText`*. All browsers in use support one or the other (maybe both). You can also use a regular expression (indexOf works too, a RegExp is just an option) so:

```
var re = new RegExp('*' + word + '*');

if (re.test(div[i].innerText || div[i].textContent)) {
  // div[i] contains /*word*/
}
```

A more robust solution would be like:

```
function getText(el) {
  if (typeof el.textContent == 'string') {
    return el.textContent;
  }
  if (typeof el.innerText == 'string') {
    return el.innerText;
  }
}

var re = new RegExp('*' + word + '*');

if (re.test(getText(div[i]))) {
  // div[i] contains /*word*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

html :

```
<div id="ok">Hello world</div>
```

javascript :

```
var ok;

ok = document.getElementById("ok").innerHTML

if (ok.includes("world")) {
  document.getElementById("ok").innerHTML = "its working";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to explain your answer rather than just posting code. Especially since this is an old question with other answers, it's important to state why yours is different or improves on the others.

Answer (score 0):

use regexp:

```
if ( divs[i].textContent.match ( /\bword\b/ ) ){
    //do something
}
```

@RobG remind me so

```
if ( divs[i].innerHTML.match ( /\bword\b/ ) ){
    //do something
}
```

=3=

Comment: Will not work in browsers that don't support the W3C DOM *textContent* property.

Comment: Also, regex is slower and takes much more processing compared to indexOf

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="single-headlines">
        <li>Fixed Shipping Sek 29</li>
        <li>44/5 Trustpilot</li>
        <li>Fast Delivery</li>
    </ul>

<script>
jQuery(".single-headlines > li:first").text(function () {
    return jQuery(this).text().replace("Fixed Shipping Sek 29", "Fast fraktkostnad SEK 29"); 
});
jQuery(".single-headlines > li:nth-child(3)").text(function () {
    return jQuery(this).text().replace("Fast Delivery", "Snabb leverans"); 
});
</script>
```

By selector Find the text which have to replace. **text()** return the selected text element **replace()** change the text.