# Check if a page contains text, if true add class to parent class using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript and trying to implement this code, I searched for something similar and tried a bunch of solutions, they are not working for me.

I'm trying to hide or show a div using javascript if page contains a specific text.

We need to show the following embedded video

```
<div class="vimeovideo">
 <iframe src="{{ variant.metafields["global"]["rosecolorurl"] }}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen="" data-ready="true"></iframe>
</div>

.vimeovideo {
display:none;
}

.show {
display: block !important;
}
```

Example: If page contains text like "100 kilometers", then it should add "show " class to "vimeovideo" div.

I guess the javascript code needs some interval to allow page to load fully and then check for the text.

Page also has options, when user clicks on them it redirects to different url using ajax.

Thank you for your help.

tried from this also:

[Javascript - check if div contains a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627289/javascript-check-if-div-contains-a-word)

Comment: If you are struggling with page load time then try to use listener for window onLoad

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

  <head>

  </head>
</head>

<body>
  100 kilometers
  <script>
    if (document.body.innerText.includes("100 kilometers")) {
      console.log("100 kilometers")
    };
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you, then how to add class to "vimeovideo" when it matches that text? i'm a noob not sure how to do it

Comment: To test I tried this:

<script>
    if (document.body.innerText.includes("18K Rose Gold")) {
      $('.product__content-header').addClass('redbg');
    };
  </script>

but it didn't work

Comment: I understand, After the conditional IF you will have first to select the element 'vimeovideo' then add the class 'redbg' to it. In order to select an element you can use its ID, but since you do not have the ID you only have the className which is 'vimeovideo' when trying to select using the className (which is your case) the result will be an ARRAY of elements with that className not only one element: if(document.body.innerText.includes("18K Rose Gold")){document.getElementsByClassName("vimeovideo")[0].classList.add("redbg");}. Note that [0]  becuz we know the result if one element only

Answer (score 0):

You can call your function when page fully loads with event listeners.

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
//Your code here
});
```

You can search in the body but searching in `body` will be a bad choice. You should be more specific about your search range.

```
let b = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
b.includes("100 Kilometers");
```

Then you can add class like that

```
document.querySelector(".vimeovideo").classList.add("show");
```

Comment: thank you, then how to add class to "vimeovideo" when it matches that text?

Comment: i'm a noob not sure how to do it

Comment: @Karthik I just updated my answer. Can you please check it out ?

Comment: To test I tried this:

$(window).addEventListener("load", () => {

let b = document.getElementsByTagName('product__form-container')[0].innerHTML;

b.includes("18K Rose Gold");

document.querySelector(".product__content-header").classList.add("redbg");                   
 
});

but it didn't work

Comment: sorry, this worked

window.addEventListener("load", () => {

let b = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;

b.includes("18K Rose Gold");

document.querySelector(".product__content-header").classList.add("redbg");                   
});

Comment: it looks in the body tag and finds the text, but to be more specific I need it to match the text inside:

<label class="swatch-header">18K Rose Gold</label>

Because this text changes using ajax when user clicks on any product options

Comment: i added 'swatch-header' instead of body tag but it isn't working when i replace that

Comment: @Karthik if you want to select the element with class you can use `document.getElementsByClassName("swatch-header")` or `document.querySelector(".swatch-header")` to select your node. `getElementsByTagName` is used for only tag names like `div`, `body`, `p` etc.

Comment: @Karthik Happy to hear that. Can you please check this answer as accepted answer. This way we can show the working solution to other people struggling. You can do that by clicking the check button at the top left of my answer.

Comment: I clicked on it and got a message that my reputation is lower than 15, so it won't affect anything.