# How to select html element that seems to another in css

Tags: html, css

I have two elements that are very seems to each other.

```
<td class="order_table_cell" data-title="status">Processing</td>
```

And I have another one element has same class and data title name:

```
<td class="order_table_cell" data-title="status">Complete</td>
```

I have no access on HTML. and I want to add css on only "Complete" cell.

I tried to use this css code but it changes both on my page.

```
.order_table_cell[data-title="status"]{color: green;}
```

Is there anyway to implement that?

My full html code:

```
    <table class="woocommerce-orders-table woocommerce-MyAccount-orders shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders account-orders-table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="woocommerce-orders-table__header woocommerce-orders-table__header-order-number"><span class="nobr">الطلب</span></th>
<th class="woocommerce-orders-table__header woocommerce-orders-table__header-order-date"><span class="nobr">التاريخ</span></th>
<th class="woocommerce-orders-table__header woocommerce-orders-table__header-order-status"><span class="nobr">الحالة</span></th>
<th class="woocommerce-orders-table__header woocommerce-orders-table__header-order-total"><span class="nobr">الإجمالي</span></th>
<th class="woocommerce-orders-table__header woocommerce-orders-table__header-order-actions"><span class="nobr">إجراءات</span></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="woocommerce-orders-table__row woocommerce-orders-table__row--status-completed order">
<td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-number" data-title="الطلب">
<a href="https://tasawwq.com/my-account/view-order/7468/">
#7468 </a>
</td>
<td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-date" data-title="التاريخ">
<time datetime="2020-12-10T17:09:15+00:00">2020-12-10</time>
</td>
<td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-status" data-title="الحالة">
مُكتمل
</td>
<td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-total" data-title="الإجمالي">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">3,299.0&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">ج.م</span></span> لـ 3 عناصر
</td>
<td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-actions" data-title="إجراءات">
<a href="https://tasawwq.com/my-account/view-order/7468/" class="woocommerce-button button view">عرض</a> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: if **Complete** td next to **Processing** td than you can used this css: `.order_table_cell + .order_table_cell {color: green;}`

Comment: no the table has 5 columns filled with order details, (num, name, status, date, see more).
each one of them is reapeated for each row as each row is presented a single order.
so "Processing" and "Complete" are in the same column but different rows.

Comment: Please share your table html code

Comment: I couldn't reply in a comment with the code, so I edited my post. please check the code.

Comment: look it (css) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text and it (js) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627289/javascript-check-if-div-contains-a-word/42930535

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see in the code when order completed then `.woocommerce-orders-table__row--status-completed` class added in `<tr>` so you can use this class to change color for order status `td`

```
tr.woocommerce-orders-table__row--status-completed td.woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-status{
    color:green;
}
```

```css
tr.woocommerce-orders-table__row--status-completed td.woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-status{
    color:green;
}
```

```html
<table class="woocommerce-orders-table woocommerce-MyAccount-orders shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders account-orders-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th class="woocommerce-orders-table__header woocommerce-orders-table__header-order-number"><span class="nobr">الطلب</span></th>
    <th class="woocommerce-orders-table__header woocommerce-orders-table__header-order-date"><span class="nobr">التاريخ</span></th>
    <th class="woocommerce-orders-table__header woocommerce-orders-table__header-order-status"><span class="nobr">الحالة</span></th>
    <th class="woocommerce-orders-table__header woocommerce-orders-table__header-order-total"><span class="nobr">الإجمالي</span></th>
    <th class="woocommerce-orders-table__header woocommerce-orders-table__header-order-actions"><span class="nobr">إجراءات</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="woocommerce-orders-table__row woocommerce-orders-table__row--status-completed order">
      <td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-number" data-title="الطلب">
      <a href="https://tasawwq.com/my-account/view-order/7468/">
      #7468 </a>
      </td>
      <td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-date" data-title="التاريخ">
      <time datetime="2020-12-10T17:09:15+00:00">2020-12-10</time>
      </td>
      <td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-status" data-title="الحالة">
      مُكتمل
      </td>
      <td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-total" data-title="الإجمالي">
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">3,299.0&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">ج.م</span></span> لـ 3 عناصر
      </td>
      <td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-actions" data-title="إجراءات">
      <a href="https://tasawwq.com/my-account/view-order/7468/" class="woocommerce-button button view">عرض</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="woocommerce-orders-table__row woocommerce-orders-table__row--status-processing order">
      <td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-number" data-title="الطلب">
      <a href="https://tasawwq.com/my-account/view-order/7468/">
      #7468 </a>
      </td>
      <td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-date" data-title="التاريخ">
      <time datetime="2020-12-10T17:09:15+00:00">2020-12-10</time>
      </td>
      <td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-status" data-title="الحالة">
      مُكتمل
      </td>
      <td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-total" data-title="الإجمالي">
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">3,299.0&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">ج.م</span></span> لـ 3 عناصر
      </td>
      <td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-actions" data-title="إجراءات">
      <a href="https://tasawwq.com/my-account/view-order/7468/" class="woocommerce-button button view">عرض</a> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this will change the status color to be green. I want it to be green only if it is Completed order.

Comment: yes, this css only for completed order, you can see in my update code

Comment: I implemented the code and it worked ! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) for text content

You can't do it with pure CSS

You can do it if you can change HTML (server or client side)

e.g. with JavaScript like this to change the HTML

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.order_table_cell[data-title="status"]'))
    .filter(element => element.textContent === "Complete")
    .forEach(element => element.classList.add("completed"))
```

```css
.completed{color: green;}
```